# Change Class of Parent Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web app that populates a table and I need to set the background colour of some of the cells according to the value that is stored in them.  I have Googled various javascript and jQuery solutions but nothing seems to be quite what I am looking for.

EDIT:

The HTML is insignificant.  The relevant portion is just:

```
<td class="green"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="t3r3c3" /></td>
```

In the code-behind I have this:

```
string controlIndex = tableIndex + "r" + row.ToString() + "c" + col.ToString();
Literal cellTarget = (Literal)form1.FindControl(controlIndex);
cellTarget.Text = cellValue;
if (controlIndex.Equals("t3r3c3") && Convert.ToDouble(dr[dc]) >= 0.7)
{
    // Code to change class of parent element <td> to red here.
}
```

The value for the cell in question is unpredictable.  By default the background colour is green but I might need to switch it to yellow or red depending on the value in the cell.

EDIT:

Here is the rendered HTML of the line in question.  Above 70% I need to change the class to yellow or red.

```
<tr><td class="green">40%</td><td class="green">30%</td><td class="green">70%</td><td class="green">48%</td><td class="green">43%</td><td class="green">90%</td></tr>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some of your HTML so we can see exactly how to help?

Comment: Have you tried `someJQueryObject.parent().addClass('foo')`?

Comment: What are you using to create the table? Is it pulling in with AJAX or something that is pre-populated? Do you have an example url?

Comment: If the value is set statically or on the server, then you can simply set the css class for those cells into the html directly. Can you explain why you need to do this via javascript, maybe with a code example?

Comment: Are your values fixed amount, meaning do you always get the same amount of values in the cells? If this is the case you can create css classes with these values and assign them to cells.

Comment: Have you tried `elem.parentElement.className += 'class';`?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as your post has no code, it is difficult to provide proper assistance, but to answer your question directly, you could set a parent's element class with `$(this).parent().addClass('yourClass');`, to change, you could use `$(this).parent().attr("class", "yourClass");`